# Get the last inserterd row mysql

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have two tables **assignment** and **class_users** from which I'm getting the data to populate the table **assigned_users**. I added the **after insert** trigger below to the **assignment** table:

```
INSERT INTO assigned_users
(assignment_id, user_id) 
SELECT a.new.uniqueid, c.user_id
FROM assignment a inner join class_users c on a.class_id = c.class_id;
```

I want from every insertion on **assignment** table to get the **uniqueid** column and insert it into assigned_users.

**NOTE** the table **class_users** it is already populated.

With a single table I can do it, but with table joining it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would need a join here. The data from the new row in the `assignment` table can be accessed by the `NEW` alias (`a.new.uniqueid` should be just `new.uniqueid`). All you need is to select the related row from the `class_users` table:

```
INSERT INTO assigned_users (assignment_id, user_id) 
SELECT new.uniqueid, c.user_id
FROM class_users c 
WHERE c.class_id = new.class_id;
```